Vuetify3 autocomplete inner-icon not focus

From Vuetify 3.5.10 and above, the focus is on append-inner.
I would like to fix this so that the inner-icon does not have focus, but the tabindex is set to 0.
Is there any way to change it to -1?
<i
  class="v-icon notranslate v-theme--dark v-icon--size-default v-icon--clickable v-autocomplete__menu-icon"
  role="button"
  aria-hidden="false"
  tabindex="0"
  aria-label="Open"
  title="Open"
  ><svg
    class="v-icon__svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    role="img"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <path d="M7,10L12,15L17,10H7Z"></path></svg
></i>

props setting change but focused.

You can run this when the component is mounted
document.getElementsByClassName('v-autocomplete__menu-icon')[0].tabIndex = -1


thank you!
const icons = document.getElementsByClassName('v-autocomplete__menu-icon');
    for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        const elm = icons[i] as HTMLElement;
        elm.tabIndex = -1;
    }

